# How can I install aria2c 1.36 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, snap

I've tried multiple combinations of `apt` and `snap` and

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aria2/aria2_1.36.0-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i aria2_1.36.0-1_amd64.deb
```

But I always end up with dependency issues or a non-working binary.

Comment: How does *snap* relate?   You `snap install` snap packages; and do not use `dpkg` or *deb* packages with *snap* commands (or vise-versa)

Comment: @guiverc Some website said use snap. snap does have an aria2c package. Do you have a solution?

Comment: the question is: what does the dependency issue have to do with a snap install? snaps are independent install :) https://snapcraft.io/install/aria2c/ubuntu it does not list a version but snap is likely the newest stable.

Comment: Sorry my mind gravitated to the *snap* & was confused; so commented only on that without looking further. I see `aria2 | 1.33.1-1       | bionic/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` for *bionic* or 18.04; you appear to be trying to use the *jammy* version which isn't for 18.04.

Comment: Do you receive any errors when you install via snaps?
https://snapcraft.io/aria2c

    `sudo snap install aria2c`

Comment: If you install https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/aria2 on a *bionic* system you'll need to upgrade all *depends* packages too, which will cause other *depends* packages to need upgrade etc... ie. the result is you won't likely be using a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS anymore. `libc6` is a pretty core package and 18.04's package doesn't meet it (neither does 20.04's)... I'd view `ubuntu-support-status` and see what is supported; as post-install that won't look like it does now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of dependencies which need backporting. You are not alone with this problem, so really this new Aria2 version is available in compiled deb packages from two Rob Savoury's PPAs:

- [`ppa:savoury1/backports`](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=bionic);
- [`ppa:savoury1/utilities`](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/utilities?field.series_filter=bionic).

Adding any of these PPAs to the system will cause upgrade of many packages to new versions. If you are sure with walking this way - use commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aria2 --only-upgrade
```

Then you will have two choices:

- Upgrade all other packages using just added PPA by

  ```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Remove the just added PPA keeping most of the packages at their current 18.04 LTS versions while having newest Aria2 by

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:savoury1/backports
  ```

To keep system manageable I would recommend to use latter method.

---

If you do not want to add the PPA, you have to download aria2 package with its dependencies manually and install them by commands below

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/aria2_1.36.0-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/libaria2-0-dev_1.36.0-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/libaria2-0_1.36.0-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/libgnutls30_3.7.3-4ubuntu1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/libnettle8_3.7.3-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/libtasn1-6_4.18.0-4~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+files/libhogweed6_3.7.3-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/encryption/+files/libp11-kit0_0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./aria2_1.36.0-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libaria2-0-dev_1.36.0-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libaria2-0_1.36.0-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libgnutls30_3.7.3-4ubuntu1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libnettle8_3.7.3-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libtasn1-6_4.18.0-4~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libhogweed6_3.7.3-1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb ./libp11-kit0_0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1~18.04.sav0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks! i was rocking v1.36 after just your first 3 lines